# Getting all value that is max occurrence of each row of numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to gather all the values that repeated the most in each row of the numpy array, like the result of `np.unique`.
However, I want to avoid loops as the data to be handle will be much larger (much more rows).

See the example below

Input: `a` is a 2D array, had the shape of `(x, k)`, where `x` would be very large.
`a = np.asarray([[2, 7, 7, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])`

Ideal output: `[[2,7], [5], [6]]`, first row had `[2,7]` both exist in 2 times

Using loops can nearly do the job, but `np.unique` seems not working the same for multi-dimension arrays

```py
[np.array(np.unique(i, return_counts=1)) for i in a]

# decent output
> [array([[1, 2, 7],[1, 2, 2]], dtype=int64), 
   array([[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 1, 1, 2]], dtype=int64),
   array([[6], [5]], dtype=int64)]


# Multi-dimension Input
np.unique(a, return_counts=1, axis=1)

# Useless Output
> (array([[1, 2, 2, 7, 7],
        [5, 1, 5, 2, 3],
        [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode):

```
from statistics import multimode

out = list(map(multimode, a))
```

Output:

```
[[2, 7], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on `mode`. But yeah, `statistics` is the right package here...

Comment: This hadn't occurred to me at all, but is clearly the way to go - any good resources on how this performs? Its documentation is clear about it not competing with packages like numpy and scipy and I was wondering if it substantially outperforms a comprehension or whether a numpy-native answer might still be faster?

Comment: @Grismar I haven't had a chance to time it yet (I'm on my phone). I think the timing might depend on the data, for instance if you have few unique values, it might be better to pre-process with numpy.

Comment: I timed the current solutions - no obvious numpy implementation that would be faster comes to mind, but perhaps someone has a surprise in store. I think yours is the answer here.

Comment: @Grismar thanks for timing, I have a [fully vectorial numpy solutio](https://pastebin.com/2Y2emA1m), but it has many steps and I doubt it would be more efficient than a loop ;)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the result won't have a fixed shape, since there may be ties for frequency on a row, it may be best to just generate a list of results (which involves a 'loop' in the comprehension):

```
import numpy as np


def most_frequent_values(arr):
    def most_frequent(row):
        values, counts = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
        return values[counts == np.max(counts)]

    return [most_frequent(row) for row in arr]


example = np.array([[1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 4, 5, 5], [6, 7, 7, 6]])
print(most_frequent_values(example))
```

Output:

```
[array([2]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7])]
```

If you don't need all the results in every case (maybe you're looking for a specific row that meets some condition, or you need them page by page, you could consider a generator instead:

```
import numpy as np


def most_frequent_values(arr):
    def most_frequent(row):
        values, counts = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
        return values[counts == np.max(counts)]

    for r in arr:
        yield most_frequent(r)


example = np.array([[1, 2, 2, 3], [4, 4, 5, 5], [6, 7, 7, 6]])
print(list(most_frequent_values(example)))
```

The end result is the same, but if you only use part of the data, the rest is never computed, so it may perform far better. You also get the first data sooner, which may be beneficial in some cases.

Edit:

User @mozway pointed out the obvious answer I missed, using `statistics.multimode`. Given the variable size of the result, I think you may have trouble coming up with a vectorisable solution using only numpy and scipy (or similar high performing libraries) that outperforms it.

Here's a comparison:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np
from statistics import multimode


def most_frequent_values_numpy_comprehension(arr):
    def most_frequent(row):
        values, counts = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
        return values[counts == np.max(counts)]

    return [most_frequent(r) for r in arr]


def most_frequent_values_numpy_generator(arr):
    def most_frequent(row):
        values, counts = np.unique(row, return_counts=True)
        return values[counts == np.max(counts)]

    for r in arr:
        yield most_frequent(r)


def exhaust_most_frequent_values_numpy_generator(arr):
    return list(most_frequent_values_numpy_generator(arr))


def most_frequent_values_statistics(arr):
    return list(map(multimode, arr))


def most_frequent_values_statistics_generator(arr):
    for r in arr:
        yield multimode(r)


def exhaust_most_frequent_values_statistics_generator(arr):
    return list(most_frequent_values_statistics_generator(arr))


n = 10000
m = 10

test_data = np.array(
    [[np.random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
)
reference = most_frequent_values_statistics(test_data)


def check_reference(data):
    return len(reference) == len(data) and all(np.array_equal(np.sort(a), np.sort(b)) for a, b in zip(reference, data))


def run(f, data):
    assert check_reference(f(data))
    print(f.__name__)
    print(timeit(lambda: f(data), number=10))


run(most_frequent_values_numpy_comprehension, test_data)
run(exhaust_most_frequent_values_numpy_generator, test_data)
run(most_frequent_values_statistics, test_data)
run(exhaust_most_frequent_values_statistics_generator, test_data)
```

Output (specific to my machine, of course):

```
most_frequent_values_numpy_comprehension
1.6175812000001315
exhaust_most_frequent_values_numpy_generator
1.6418578999946476
most_frequent_values_statistics
0.3045085999983712
exhaust_most_frequent_values_statistics_generator
0.30322780000278726
```

`statistics.multimode` is the clear winner - it's concise, and relatively fast. I do consistently see that the generator is ever so slightly faster than the `map()` solution, but I like the `map()` solution for readability. However, if you're not sure to exhaust the source data, the generator should be preferred.

Regardless, you should probably accept @mozway's answer. Mine's just here for added info.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. However, I would like to prevent to use List Comprehension (similar as a For loop) as that's still quite slow for handling a large amount of data.

Comment: I've updated mine, and unless someone does come up with something very clever in numpy/scipy/... I think @mozway has the correct answer.